# Show that $\frac{g^{N}(t)}{N!}=\sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}h^{\alpha}$

Tags: analysis

Let $f(\vec{x})$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function of $n$-variables. Let $g(t)=f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})$. Show that $\frac{g^{N}(t)}{N!}=\sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}.h^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha !=\alpha_1!...\alpha_n!, |\alpha|=\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...\alpha_n, \vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$

For $n=1$ it is clear. I can differentiate and do it for $n=2$.

Let's assume it for N i.e $\frac{g^{N}(t)}{N!}=\sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}.h^{\alpha}$. Then $$g^{N}(t)=N!\sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}.h^{\alpha}$$, Thus $$g^{N+1}(t)=N!\left(h_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+h_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+...+h_n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)\left(\sum_{|\alpha|=N}\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}.h^{\alpha}\right)$$

$$=N!\sum_{|\alpha|=N,j}h_j\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}.h^{\alpha}\right)=N!\sum_{|\alpha|=N,j}h^{\alpha+e_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\frac{D^{\alpha}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}{\alpha !}\right)$$
$$=N!\sum_{|\beta|=N+1,j}h^{\beta} c_{\beta}\left({D^{\beta}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{h})}\right)$$
where  $h^{\alpha+e_j}=h_{1}^{\alpha_1}h_{2}^{\alpha_2}..h_{j}^{\alpha_{j}+1}..h_{n}^{\alpha_{n}}$.
I need to calculate $c_{\beta}$.  Here $$c_{\beta}=\sum_{\alpha, \alpha +e_J=\beta}\frac{1}{\alpha!}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\beta_1 !..(\beta_j -1) !....\beta_n !}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{\beta_j}{\beta !}=\frac{N+1}{\beta !}$$

Is it alright??

Thanks for the help!!